# MySQL - Get row if other rows match

Tags: mysql

```
entry_id                 cat_id
----------------         ----------------
1                        1
1                        2
1                        3
2                        2
3                        4
```

I know the title isn't very helpful, but I basically, I need to return the entry ID of a row, if certain categories are set.

So for example I need to return the entry_id which has the a cat_id of 1, and either 2 or 3.

Would be nice if we could avoid duplicates results, but I can always remove duplicates with PHP after if it's not possible.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: its really unclear what your result should be. i just guessed. can you write your wished result ?

Comment: Ditto. Using the sample data above, which `entry_id` values should be returned - and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.entry_id
FROM yourTable t1
JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.entry_id = t2.entry_id
WHERE t1.cat_id = 1
AND t2.cat_id IN (2, 3)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although I had to change `SELECT DISTINCT entry_id` to `SELECT DISTINCT t1.entry_id`.

Comment: Thank you for figuring out the solution yourself, instead of just pasting the error message and waiting for it to be done for you.

Comment: If you do that you never learn, I actually got pretty close to what you suggested before I posted here, I was just missing the JOIN statement. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: I can die happy, I found a SO questioner who wants to learn instead of just getting people to do the work for them. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT  entry_id
  FROM table1 
  WHERE cat_id = 1
  OR cat_id IN (2, 3)
  GROUP BY entry_id
```

Since its unclear what you are asking, I will give other attempt:

```
 SELECT  entry_id
 FROM table1 
 WHERE cat_id = 1
 AND   (cat_id = 2 or cat_id = 3)
 GROUP BY by entry_id
```

Comment: I am not clear on the desired result either, but I *think* they mean "find all entry_id's where the cat_id = 1, which *also* have a matching record for that same entry_id and either cat_id = 2 or 3). If so, [Barmar's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22354992/104223) is may be the way to go.

Comment: The second query can never return anything. How can one row have both `cat_id = 1` and `cat_id = 2`? That's why the self-join is needed in my answer, because you need to compare different rows.

Comment: Thats exactly it, but unfortunately, neither of these work. When the WHERE and IN are combined, it returns nothing.

Comment: @KeironLowe as i said , why dont you post your wished result , so i can understand what you want.

Comment: While it's true that an example wouldn't hurt, he described the desired result in perfectly good English. Imagine cat 1 = shirts, cat 2 = red, cat 3 = blue -- he wants a list of all red or blue shirts.

Comment: @Barmar's solution worked. My wished result would have been '1'. Since  that entry_id has a cat_id of '1', and either '2' or '3'.